# How avoid \t being converted to Tab in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to retrieve a parameter value from a config a file.

```
(Get-Content C:\<ConfigFolder>\basic.conf | ConvertFrom-StringData)."FileLocation"
```

The value of the "FileLocation" is "C:\temp".

And, value printed on screen is;

```
"C:     emp"
```

Looks like "\t" is parsed as a Tab.

Is there a way avoid this and print the as original value as is?

File content is as below;

```
UpdatedTime="2024-03-26 09:55:00"
FileLocation="C:\temp"
```

Comment: Yes, a literal `"\t"` in the input of `ConvertFrom-StringData` is parsed as a a Tab character. To prevent that, replace `"\t"` by `"\\t"` like this: `(Get-Content FileName).Replace('\t', '\\t') | ConvertFrom-StringData`

Comment: @Olaf - Below is the contents of the file. A very simple one at the moment.

UpdatedTime="2024-03-26 09:55:00"
FileLocation="C:\temp"

Comment: @zett42 - Thanks. It worked.
A follow-up on the same; Is there a generic way to avoid such parsing. Or, we have replace all potential scenarios explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) has provided the crucial pointer:

From the [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata) help topic (emphasis added), as of PowerShell 7.4.x:

> `ConvertFrom-StringData` supports escape character sequences that are allowed by conventional machine translation tools. That is, the **cmdlet can interpret backslashes (`\`) *as escape characters* in the string data** [...] You **can also preserve a literal backslash in your results by escaping it with a preceding backslash, like this: `\\`**. Unescaped backslash characters, such as those that are commonly used in file paths, can render as illegal escape sequences in your results.

Therefore, **assuming that all `\` characters in your input file are meant to be interpreted *literally***:

```bash
(Get-Content -Raw C:\<ConfigFolder>\basic.conf).Replace('\', '\\') |
  ConvertFrom-StringData).FileLocation
```

Note the use of `-Raw` with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) to ensure that the file content is read *in full*, as a single, (typically) *multiline* string, which in turn ensures that `ConvertFrom-StringData` outputs a *single* `[hashtable]` instance.
(If, by contrast, you really mean to output a separate hashtable *for each input line*, omit `-Raw`).

---

Given that this escaping need may be inconvenient (and possibly somewhat unexpected, but that cannot be helped), **it would be helpful if `ConvertFrom-StringData` itself supported *verbatim* (literal) parsing by way of an *opt-in***:

- [GitHub issue #20418](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20418) asks for just that, by way of a future `-Raw` switch. This enhancement has been green-lit, but is yet to be implemented.